# How to filter data using a slider in vega-lite?

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I am using the following code to plot a bubble plot using vega-lite. I want to transform values as I change the year value using the slider. But it's not working.

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Drag the sliders to highlight points.",
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shre2398/InformationVisualization/main/gapminder.tsv",
    "format": {
      "type": "tsv"
    }
  },
  "title": {
    "text": "Gapminder Global Indicators",
    "anchor": "middle",
    "fontSize": 16,
    "fontWeight": 700
  },
  "config": {
    "axis": {
      "titleFontSize": 13,
      "titleFontWeight": "bold"
    }
  },
  "params": [{
    "name": "CurrentYear",
    "value": [{"year": 1977}],
    "select": {"type": "point", "fields": ["year"]},
    "bind": {
      "year": {"input": "range", "min": 1952, "max": 2007, "step": 5}
    }
  },{
    "name": "View",
    "select": "interval",
    "bind": "scales"
  }],
  "width": 650,
  "height": 400,
  "mark": {
    "type": "circle",
    "opacity": 0.8,
    "stroke": "white",
    "strokeWidth": 1
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "gdpPercap",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {"grid": false},
      "scale": {
        "type": "log",
        "base": 10
      }
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "lifeExp", 
      "type": "quantitative", 
      "axis": {"title": ""}
    },
    "size": {
      "field": "pop"
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "continent"
    }
  }
}
```

If I add the following tranform block, it doesn't work.

```json
 "transform":[{"filter": {"param": "CurrentYear"}}]
```

I have already tried the following link :
https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/interactive_query_widgets.html

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are reading in your `year` column as strings, and then using a numerical selection to filter. You can see that the `year` values are strings in the "Data Viewer" tab. Reading in the data like this works with the transform filter you suggested above:

```json
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shre2398/InformationVisualization/main/gapminder.tsv",
    "format": {
      "type": "tsv",
      "parse": {"year": "number"}
    }
  }
```